# Change resource into arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to change `resources` into `array`?

For example:

```
@video = Video.all
```

to

```
[["Test", 1],["Test2", 2],["Test3", 3]]
```

I tried `@video.to_a` but it didn't work

Comment: We need a lot more information. You haven't told us what `Video` or `resources` are composed of. Without that we can only guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to select one or more attributes:

```
Video.pluck(:name, :id)
#=> [["foo", 1], ["bar", 2], ["baz", 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

By resources you mean an ActiveRecord collection?

If so, it can be something like

```
@video.map{ |video, index| [video.name, index+1] }
```